# on linux, how to create a restricted shell with sudo ability

Tags: linux, permissions, ssh, embedded-linux

I am wanting to allow an SSH connection to Linux that restricts the users ability to see very little of the filesystem and only run a small set of commands. Mostly the commands are a set a scripts that I write.

I am inspired by products by Checkpoint and Cisco on how they grant limited simplistic access to the appliance but a more advanced user can essentially sudo into an administrative shell.

How is this typically done?

Answer (score 1):

Try chroot which sets the root directory upto which a user can access.

Check [here](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/securing-debian-howto/ap-chroot-ssh-env.en.html)

Comment: You might also want to consider security features which prevent the restricted user from uploading and executing their own code: https://github.com/cormander/tpe-lkm